# jquery animate --> css -webkit-transform: translate3d

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have an iPhone & Phonegap & JQtouch app.

Now I use:

```
$('someElement').animate(...);
```

in order to switch screens.

The problem is that the performances are quite bad.

I read that there is a much better way to do it with "css -webkit-transform: translate3d",

I need to create a simple JQuery function which gets the "div" of the new screen and then moves it from right to left in 350ms. When the animation is done, I also need to run some other JQuery function.

Comment: Yes, using `translate3d` on iOS is actually hardware accelerated and thus performance will be better. What is your question tho?

Comment: I need a JQuery function that implement this solution

Comment: I'm sorry but I doubt someone will just write the entire function for you! You should try it yourself and post any *specific* question you have here!

Answer (score 6):

css

```
#layer{

    -webkit-transition-duration: 350ms;

    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,600px,0);

    position: absolute;

}
```

jquery

```
$('#layer').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)');
```